# Parse Cloud Code Generate List based on a Review (object)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am struggling with Parse Cloud code. I am trying to create a list of breweries based on a user reviews. I think I would need to calculate the average review for each brewery and then use this value to generate the list. I want to only include breweries with an average of 4 or higher.

Please forgive my ignorance on the matter, thanks in advance!

This is what I have and it doesn't work.

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("reviewAvergae", function(request){
    var Review = Parse.Object.extend("Reviews");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Reviews");
    query.get(request.object.get("rating").id, {
        success: function(reviews) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < reviews; i++) {
                sum += reviews[i].get("rating");
            }
            var ave = sum / reviews.length;
            reviews.set("average", ave);
            reviews.save();
        }
    });
/*
    query.equalTo("breweryId", request.params.brewId);
    query.find({
        success: function(result) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                sum += result[i].get("rating");

            }
            Review.set("averageRating", sum / result.length);
            Review.save();
            console.log(sum / result.length);
        }
    });
*/
});
Parse.Cloud.define("featured", function(request, response) {


  var query = new Parse.Query("Reviews");
//   query.near("location", request.params.loc);
  query.withinMiles("location", request.params.loc, 50);
  query.limit(10);

  query.find({
      success: function(results) {
          var sum = 0;
          var rating;
          var ratings = new Array();
          var id;
          var ids = new Array();

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

              id = results[i].get("breweryId");
              ids.push(id);
              }





          response.success(results);
           console.log(ratings.length);




      },
      error: function() {
          response.error("No breweriers in your area have been reviewed.");
      }

  });

});
```

On parse my Review Object looks like this:

[image: Review Object on Parse]

Note: My actual app is for iOS and written in swift.

Update: I have tried the following after adding a brewery object. I now get the following error : [Error]: function not found (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.5)

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Reviews", function(request){
    var Review = Parse.Object.extend("Reviews");
    var breweryId = Review.get("breweryId");

    var query = new Parse.Query("Reviews");
query.equalTo("breweryId", breweryId);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object =  results[i];
            total += object.get("rating");
        }
        var averageRating = total / results.length;

        console.log(averageRating);

        var query = new Parse.Query("Brewery");
        query.equalTo("breweryId", breweryId);



    }, error: function() {

    }
  });

});
```

here are some updated images of my my Objects in Parse

[image: Brewery Object]

[image: Reviews Object]

Comment: The more important task at hand would be to get the average review for a brewery after saving the review. The first bit of my code is attempting to do that, however I'm a little lost/stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Understand from the comments that there's an external system with Brewery objects.  In order to do parse.com computations about breweries, it will be necessary to represent them internal to parse, even if it is basically a pointer to an object in another system.

So, add a "Brewery" object.  It will get an objectId from parse, but you should add a "breweryId" string attribute, as you have with your Review class.  It should also have an "averageRating" number attribute.

Now we need logic to compute and save the average rating, given a breweryId (that's the external id, not the parse objectId)...

```
// a very helpful toolkit for dealing with js, especially arrays
var _ = require('underscore');

function updateAverageRatingForBreweryWithId(breweryId) {
    var average;
    // get all of the reviews for this breweryId
    var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
    query.equalTo("breweryId", breweryId);
    return query.find().then(function(reviews) {
        // pull out each review's rating attribute
        var ratings = _.map(reviews, function(review) { return review.get("rating"); });
        // this is just an average computation, summing the ratings and dividing by their count
        average = _.reduce(ratings, function(memo, num) { return memo + num; }, 0) / (ratings.length === 0 ? 1 : ratings.length);

        // go get the parse.com Brewery object for this breweryId
        // we will save the average rating there
        var query = new Parse.Query("Brewery");
        query.equalTo("breweryId", breweryId);
        return query.first();
    }).then(function(brewery) {
        brewery.set("averageRating", average);
        return brewery.save();
    });
}
```

This function takes an external breweryId as input, gets the reviews for that brewery, computes the average, then finds (your new) Brewery object with that breweryId sets its averageRating and saves it.

A good place to call this is after saving a Review, which is what it looked like you were up to in the original post.  That afterSave must be named (first parameter) "Review" if you want it to work on the Review object (not the name you gave it or "Comment", which @RyanKreager mentions for some reason)...

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Review", function(request) {
    var review = request.object;
    var breweryId = review.get("breweryId");
    updateAverageRatingForBreweryWithId(breweryId);
});
```

Now with a Brewery object we're in a position to query it with the real goal:  what are the highly rated breweries near me?  I can add some additional advice for that, but it only makes sense if you create a Brewery object.

Comment: The only JavaScript I am writing is the Cloud code stuff. My app is written in Swift and my knowledge of JavaScript is limited. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess that shows you how familiar I am with Cloud Code.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of errors:

1. You should be storing the `average` field on the `Brewery` object, not the review. That way you just update one object and you can do a nice, tidy query for all the `Brewery` objects where `average > x` etc.
2. `breweryId` is a string. This should be a pointer to the `Brewery` object. Also change the name to just `brewery`
3. Once you have those two things cleared up, something like this makes more sense for the `afterSave` on a `Review` object:

Your `afterSave` needed some adjustments. Try this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Comment", function(request) {
   var Review = Parse.Object.extend("Review");
   var query = new Parse.Query(Review);
   query.equalTo("brewery", request.object.get("brewery"));
   query.find({
     success: function(results) {
     // Find the average from all the brewery reviews
     var total = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       var object = results[i];
       total += object.get("rating");
     }
     var averageRating = total / results.length;

     var updatedObjects = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       var object = results[i];
       object.set("average", averageRating);
       updatedObjects.push(object);
     }
     Parse.Object.saveAll(updatedObjects);
   }, error: function(error) {
     alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't have a brewery object, I am using breweryDbs API for the brewery information. I'm only using Parse as a way to store reviews, save a brewery as a favorite, and provide a list of suggested breweries. Is there anyway to do what I want with just the review object?

Comment: Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Yes, but you're setting yourself up for a LOT of suffering. You basically have two databases that don't talk to each other. A better solution would be to add a brewery object to Parse for every brewery you access. It doesn't have to have everything from the breweryDbs system, but can act as a nice go-between and store information germane to your breweries (like review averages). Much cleaner :)

Comment: I don't have time to retire my app at the moment. I need a solution that will work without changing my apps logic. Also what type of data would I store with your proposed solution?

Comment: @TylerMiller47 - where do you want the average rating to be saved?  I think the app can stay mostly intact, but the idea of saving an average rating as part of the Review is strange, because the average is the result of many Reviews.

Comment: @danh It really doesn't matter where the average is saved. I just need it to create a list of the highest rated breweries.

Comment: Okay.   The key words in your comment is "list of [...] breweries".  To get this from parse, you'll need a Brewery object.  Its fine that the real brewery object is foreign, just refer to the foreign object your parse object, the same way you do in review.  I'll add an answer that covers this, as well as correcting the save/query/average rating logic.

Comment: @TylerMiller47 if you store the review average on the review, it can cause errors in the average rating - not to mention you have to update EVERY review that matches that brewery every time a new one is created. Do you have a compelling reason not to change the app in a new release?

Comment: @RyanKreager I need to something working by tomorrow, its for a school project. I plan to fix it the correct way, just given my time frame for completion I fear I won't get done.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your needs. WARNING: This is a stupidly resource-intensive way to do this. Fix immediately.

Comment: @danh what exactly do you mean by "just refer to the foreign object your parse object"? Also not sure it will make much of difference but the app is for iOS and written in Swift.

Comment: In your Review object, you have an attribute called breweryId.  I understand that from your comments to mean that it's an identifier of a brewery in some other system... "I don't have a brewery object, I am using breweryDbs API for the brewery information".

Comment: @RyanKreager I plan to fix it properly just in a rush, as I don't have much time. Also not too sure what the correct way would be like. And thanks!

Comment: This should work for now - you can open a new question later for help with a more scalable version :) (Also, if this helps please don't forget to upvote and mark correct!)

Comment: You're going to provide more information in order for me to help you. Where does it fail? What does it do / not do?

Comment: @RyanKreager I keep getting  function not found (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.5) also what was your original answer when you referenced a brewery object?